# Using a nested loop on multiple array lists

Tags: arraylist, export-to-excel, nested-loops

So I have 3 array lists and they are all the same size, I'm trying to print them in an excel file which works however the IP and GEO are only returning the first value over and over.

This is my code:

```
for (String url : IPGrabber.URLArray) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(url);
        for (String ip : IPGrabber.IPArray) {
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(ip);
        }
        for (String geo : GEOLookup.GEOArray) {
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(geo);
        }
}
```

This is the output in excel

```
http://www.google.com   199.59.148.82   United States
http://www.google.com   199.59.148.82   United States
http://www.mcbay.net    199.59.148.82   United States
http://www.facebook.com 199.59.148.82   United States
http://twitter.com  199.59.148.82   United States
```

As you can see the URLArray and IPArray are repeatign same value

Any help would be greatly appreciated attempted many different methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong the for loop. You must do something similar to:

java-like syntax:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < IPGrabber.URLArray.size(); i++ )
{
 Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
 row.createCell(0).setCellValue(IPGrabber.URLArray.get(i));
 row.createCell(1).setCellValue(IPGrabber.IPArray.get(i));
 row.createCell(2).setCellValue(GEOLookup.GEOArray.get(i));
}
```

As arrayList have same size.

Answer (score 0):

**if** the arrays are always the same size, you could write it like this:

*Java example*

```
for ( int i = 0; i < IPGrabber.URLArray.getSize(); i++ )
{
    String url = IPGrabber.URLArray.elementAt(i);
    String ip = IPGrabber.IPArray.elementAt(i);
    String geo = GEOLookup.GEOArray.elementAt(i);

    // TODO: code to insert into the cell
}
```

EDIT: Actually I see your mistake now ... the two inner loops will **always** end up inserting their last element into that rows cell - which is why you are always getting the same value. Change the code as I've suggested and it'll work.

Comment: What do you mean by the elementAt in this statement?

Comment: elementAt(index) is bascially the same as get(index) - it is commonly used in Java and you never said which language you used, so I wrote the reply in Java style.